# Is there a specification that outlines the OAuth 2 consent page?

Tags: oauth

In OAuth2 an authorization server typically presents the user with a consent page asking if they would like the client application to access their information. For example if a site is configured to sign in with Google via OAuth 2 I would see a screen like so

```
Client application X is trying to access the following personal information:

email
login_name
friends list

Do you consent?
```

But the consent page is not part of the [OAuth 2 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). Is there any RFC or other specification that outlines or attempts to standardize the consent page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no specification detailing the user consent page. However, [RFC 6819 (OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819), which is an informative document (not a standards track), discusses the use of a consent page. It doesn't outline any specifications in regards to what belongs on the page, etc... but it encourages the use of such a page in order to mitigate vulnerabilities when using OAuth 2. For example see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.1.3). Adding a consent page can help minimize vulnerabilities, although not necessarily prevent them. It's one more thing a nefarious user would need to bypass. The take away in regards to the consent page is that the user should always know what resources (aka scopes) a client application is requesting. Having this will make sure the user knows specifically which scopes the client wants access to. Without it, a client application could request user information without their knowledge. RFC 6819 can outline a few reasons why a consent page should be used.

Comment: Good answer. It should also be noted that not only is there no specification detailing the consent page, but also that RFC 6819 is not a standards track document; its status currently is only Informational.

Comment: I updated the answer as per your feedback. Thanks!